# Iterating and invoking heterogeneous functions inside a tuple

Tags: c++, c++11, iteration, tuples, function-pointers

In most general terms, my problem is the following one: at compile time define a sequence of heterogeneous function pointers (with potentially different arity) that later on need to be iterated and invoked in arbitrary order at runtime.

Constraining oneself to C++, what would be the most suitable container, iteration and invocation mechanism?

This problem was motivated by a real world situation to which I've later found a simpler solution not involving tuples but that is more specialized in nature.

Originally I attempted to do something like this:

```
//type variables Y... have to be convertible to parameters of every function from the tuple std::tuple<T...> in order for this to compile
template<size_t n, typename... T, typename... Y>
void callFunNth(std::tuple<T...> &tpl, size_t i, Y... args) {
    if (i == n)
        std::get<n>(tpl)(args...); 
    else
        callFunNth<(n < sizeof...(T)-1? n+1 : 0)>(tpl, i, args...);
}
template<typename... T, typename... Y>
void  callFun(std::tuple<T...> &tpl, size_t i, Y... args) {
    callFunNth<0>(tpl,i, args...);
}

int main() 
{
    using T1 = int;
    namespace mpi = boost::mpi;
    //Several instantiations of boost::mpi::reduce algorithm I am interested in
    auto algs = make_tuple(boost::bind((void (*)(const mpi::communicator&, const T1*, T1, T1*, std::plus<T1>, int))mpi::reduce<T1, std::plus<T1>>, _1, _2, _3, _4, std::plus<T1>(), _5),
                           boost::bind((void (*)(const mpi::communicator&, const T1*, T1, T1*, mpi::minimum<T1>, int))mpi::reduce<T1, mpi::minimum<T1>>, _1, _2, _3, _4, mpi::minimum<T1>(), _5),
                           boost::bind((void (*)(const mpi::communicator&, const T1*, T1, T1*, std::minus<T1>, int))mpi::reduce<T1, std::minus<T1>>, _1, _2, _3, _4, std::minus<T1>(), _5)
                          );

    //Iterate through the tuple and call each algorithm
    for(size_t i=0; i < std::tuple_size<decltype(algs)>::value;i++)
        callFun(algs, i, /*actual arguments to each algorithm*/);
}
```

The problem with this approach is that for callFunNth to compile at all the supplied arguments have to be type-convertible to the parameters of all the functions inside the supplied tuple which seriously limits the heterogeneity of said functions and forces one to use std::bind or boost::bind to work around this.

When the types are mutually convertible one can write the following:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
void fja(T x, U y) { 
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
}
auto funs = std::make_tuple(fja<int,std::string>, fja<double,std::string>, fja<char,std::string>);
callFun(funs, 2, 'a', "Char");
callFun(funs, 1, 2.45, "Decimal");
callFun(funs, 0, 1, "Integer");
```

and have 'a', '2.45' and '1' sent to stdout respectively

Comment: Do you want to iterate over the tuple (which would imply equivalent arguments to all functions inside the tuple), or do you want, based on a runtime variable, get a specific function out and call that with specific parameters?

Comment: I don't think that's possible to call `callFun(funs, i, 2.45, "Decimal");`, because the compiler cannot know that the "i"-th element of the tuple can accept a double, where `i` is unknown until the runtime.

Comment: @Xeo It's the second case where any function from the tuple can be called at runtime with specific parameters (both value and type)

Comment: @KennyTM I tested it with the code provided and it does work as expected due to compile time recursion generating all the use cases

Answer (score 2):

You should store the function objects as `std::vector<std::function<const boost::mpi::communicator&, const T1*, int, T1*, int>>`. It is much easier to manage.

If you must use a tuple of functions, see below.

---

***The C++ standard library seriously need a compile-time `iota`.***

Here's an alternative method if what you need is to call all functions **using the same arguments**. First we construct the variadic integer list `integers<0, 1, 2, ..., n-1>` (copied from https://github.com/kennytm/utils/blob/master/vtmp.hpp):

```
template <size_t... ns>
struct integers
{
    template <size_t n>
    using push_back = integers<ns..., n>;

};

namespace xx_impl
{
    template <size_t n>
    struct iota_impl
    {
        typedef typename iota_impl<n-1>::type::template push_back<n-1> type;
    };

    template <>
    struct iota_impl<0>
    {
        typedef integers<> type;
    };
}

template <size_t n>
using iota = typename xx_impl::iota_impl<n>::type;
```

Then we use the unpack operation directly:

```
template <typename... T, size_t... ns, typename... Y>
void call_all_impl(const std::tuple<T...>& funcs,
                   const integers<ns...>&,
                   Y... args) {
    __attribute__((unused))
    auto f = {(std::get<ns>(funcs)(args...), 0)...};
}

template <typename T, typename... Y>
void call_all(const T& funcs, Y&&... args) {
    call_all_impl(funcs,
                  iota<std::tuple_size<T>::value>(), 
                  std::forward<Y>(args)...);
}
```

For example,

```
int main() {
    call_all(std::make_tuple([](int x, double y){ printf("1: %d %g\n", x, y); },
                             [](double x, int y){ printf("2: %e/%d\n", x, y); },
                             [](int x, int y){ printf("3: %#x %#x\n", x, y); }),
            4, 9);
}
```

prints

```
1: 4 9
2: 4.000000e+00/9
3: 0x4 0x9
```

---

A slight modification can make it call just the `i`-th argument selected at runtime.

```
template <typename... T, size_t... ns, typename... Y>
void call_one_impl(const std::tuple<T...>& funcs, size_t which,
                   const integers<ns...>&,
                   Y... args) {
    __attribute__((unused))
    auto f = {(ns == which && (std::get<ns>(funcs)(args...), 0))...};
}

template <typename T, typename... Y>
void call_one(const T& funcs, size_t which, Y&&... args) {
    call_one_impl(funcs, which,
                  iota<std::tuple_size<T>::value>(),
                  std::forward<Y>(args)...);
}
```

For example,

```
int main() {
    auto t = std::make_tuple([](int x, double y){ printf("1: %d %g\n", x, y); },
                             [](double x, int y){ printf("2: %e/%d\n", x, y); },
                             [](int x, int y){ printf("3: %#x %#x\n", x, y); });

    call_one(t, 2, 6.5, 7.5);
    call_one(t, 0, 4, 9);
    call_one(t, 1, 5.8, 8);
}
```

prints

```
3: 0x6 0x7
1: 4 9
2: 5.800000e+00/8
```

Comment: The way the edit is worded could mean that the OP wants to call a specific tuple based on a runtime variable, meaning that simple iteration won't help. :/

Comment: @Xeo: Actually it can help. See update. (I assume it is correct since both clang++ and g++ do not complain with `-pedantic -Wall -Wextra` ^^)

Comment: @KennyTM: `auto f = {(ns == which && (std::get<ns>(funcs)(args...), 0))...}` Oh! Oh! That's clever and easily generalized to an arbitrary function. You should patent it :p More seriously, there is still the issue of having functions expecting different parameters (possibly of different arities).

Comment: Well, except that's about the same the OP already has, with the same problem that all functions need to be able to accept all possible arguments. :/

Comment: @Xeo there's no way to avoid that because the `which` is determined at **runtime**. The compiler needs to expect `call_one(t, rand(), foo, bar)` to work, which means all functions need to be able to accept the provided arguments.

Comment: @KennyTM Using std::vector<std::function<const boost::mpi::communicator&, const T1*, T1, T1*, int>> was exactly what I ended up doing in this case, however I am still curious how one would solve the more general problem. From what I can see, the solution you posted here does not appear to be any more general than the one I came up with. I certainly do appreciate the effort!

Answer (score 1):

The go-to library for heterogeneous containers is [Boost.Fusion](http://www.boost.org/libs/fusion/). As you will see on that website, they use compile-time polymorphic functors for tasks like this.

Answer (score 0):

I think that its a bad idea to use tuple for storing functions
For me its more simply to create function pointer

```
typedef impl_defined pointer_to_function
```

and pushes functions into

```
std::vector<pointer_to_function>
```

Answer (score 0):

After tinkering a little bit more with this problem, I believe that using type unions might be one reasonably good way of addressing it, although I do fear that the problem as stated in its current form is a bit too vague to merit a single best answer.

Anyhow, this is how one could approach the problem using type unions in C++:

```
int main()
{
    auto f1 = [](int x) { std::cout << x << std::endl;};
    auto f2 = [](int x, std::string y) { std::cout << y << std::endl;};
    auto f3 = [](const std::vector<int> &x) { std::copy(x.begin(),x.end(),std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout," "));};
    using tFun1 = decltype(f1);
    using tFun2 = decltype(f2);
    using tFun3 = decltype(f3);
    using funUnion = boost::variant<tFun1,tFun2,tFun3>;

    std::vector<funUnion> funs = {f1,f2,f3};
    for(auto &ff : funs) {
        if (tFun1* result = boost::get<tFun1>(&ff)) (*result)(2);
        else
        if (tFun2* result = boost::get<tFun2>(&ff)) (*result)(2,"Hello!");
        else
        if (tFun3* result = boost::get<tFun3>(&ff)) (*result)({1,2,3,4,5});
    }
}
```